# Upload video to user's own YouTube account in ASP MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to build an ASP MVC web app that will allow users to upload a video from my server to their own YouTube account. I'm using the upload video code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

This is the part that deals with authentication:

```cs
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None
  );
}
```

The video is uploaded to my own YouTube account every time, even if I'm not signed into that account. I want it to upload to the user's own account, prompting them to authorize my app if necessary. How do I do this?

The YouTube account that the video is uploaded to should be the account the user is currently signed into. If they are not signed into an account, then it should prompt for a username and password. I was able to do this with Twitter and Facebook, and it looks like the same is possible with YouTube since Vimeo does it: https://twitter.com/caseypugh/status/930918571663863810